# Model for UnderReview/Published User Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, database-design

I am building a user-generated website, but want to be able to moderate them. I also need the posts have a static id, because I want to use the facebook social plugins. I was initially thinking about having two distinct tables 'review' and 'published' and move the posts from one table to another. However, I didnt know how make them retain their id, as the incremental id of the table is used?

I could also use one table and have a published attribute, but I feel this solution is not really performant, but the only way to preserve the id?

btw, i am using rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have a `state` column in the `posts` table to show if a post is reviewed or published?  If you want to get fancy you can use something like the [aasm](https://github.com/rubyist/aasm) gem.

Comment: That was my second proposal. I am just not sure how performant this is since every query will have to be filtered by this column

Comment: If the `status` column is indexed it shouldn't be a problem.